# What does 'set' do in Actionscript 2

Tags: flash, set, actionscript-2, actionscript-1

I haven't used AS2 before and I have to fix someones code which was written in AS2 and is using flash. Here is the AS2 code:

```
var evalOpt = eval("option"+optObj);
var evalPlace = eval("_root.placed"+plcObj);
trace(evalOpt);
trace(evalPlace);

set("ans"+plcObj, evalOpt);
```

I traced both evalOpt and evalPlace. evalOpt is

```
<b>0</b>
```

and evalPlace is

```
_level0.placed6
```

. What does the set() function do in AS2? I looked through the rest of his code and did not find the set() function anywhere.

Note: I have opened it in Flash and on the top it says "AS1 / AS2".. I don't know if this is AS1 or AS2, but I am assuming it is AS2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS2 `set()` function does the assignment. First parameter is variable name as `String`, second  parameter is the value you want to assign. 
Important thing to note about first parameter, is that if you have a variable say:

```
var color:String = "orange";
```

and you call

```
set(color, "blue"); // will *not* work as intended
```

then variable `color` will not be set to "blue", instead new variable named `"orange"` will be created and value "blue" assigned to it.

```
set("color", "blue"); // will work as intended
```

In your example function `set()` assigns whatever data is in variable `evalOpt` to variable  name that evaluates from `"ans"+plcObj`